# How to fix OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space] in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch, heap-memory

I am accessing elasticsearch from my java code in Eclipse and dumping all the data to my local drive. There is around 1GB of data.

My program worked till 300MB of data but after that when I try to run my code in eclipse it throws the following error:

```
{
  "error" : "OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]",
  "status" : 500
}
```

I saw online it's mentioned to add `-Xmx2048M`under Run > Run Config for the class I am running. I tried that and restarted eclipse, still getting the same error.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You are passing argument in VM arguments section or program arguments section ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to store the whole data into memory?
Do no do that.

Try to use the streaming API's from Java which will dump the data to secondary storage once the stream is full. You can define the max buffer size as per your RAM available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error message is coming from Elastic search and not from your Java Program.

Use [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html) to configure bigger heap for elastic search.

Comment: I tried starting Elasticsearch like this : ./bin/elasticsearch -Xmx10g -Xms10g